# validity check failed executing GET https://Identity Server IP:9444/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I use wso2 identity server as a KeyManager of wso2 API manager that run in two different machine. after running two server there is a error in wso2 API manager :

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.exception.GlobalThrowableMapper} - An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper. feign.RetryableException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed executing GET https://IdentityServerIP:9444/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration
at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:249)
```

I am following this [link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/) to do this and using MSSQL Server as shared database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the Identity Servers public cert to API Manager client-trustore.

Export the cert from IS

```
keytool -export -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file <public key name>.pem
```

Then in your APIM server, import the public key that you extracted to the client-trustore.

```
keytool -import -alias iskey -file <public key name>.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
```

Comment: Thanks @ycr, now there is a problem when opening https://...:9444/myaccount and console of Identity server with this error : Registered callback does not match with the provided Url.

Comment: @behzad You may have to update the Call back URL in the SP configs. Feel free to create a new SO question for the new issue.